# Are there samples for new reviewers?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

As a new reviewer, I think it would be helpful to have lists of examples from experienced reviewers for the different categories. It would help me know whether I understand the guidelines correctly.

If this already exists, how do I find it?

Comment: We also need an "Editors 101" course. Almost all editors want to help but there's almost no way for them to learn what are good and not-so-good edits.

Comment: Ha ha :) Whoever builds that is going to prove they themselves don't understand the guidelines correctly.

Comment: You can find some examples reading the questions in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specific-audit. This is not fully representative of all reviews and also not nicely formatted as a list or a tutorial, but it could be a start.

Comment: #Gimby Could you be more specific about what you mean.

Comment: Reviewing is a difficult process with many gotchas; just like chess it it easy to learn and hard to master. Anyone who is going to attempt to setup examples is going to go through a gruelling review process where people will point out many mistakes they themselves always thought to be the correct interpretation of a guideline. It is kind of a daunting task, I can imagine.

Comment: #Marijin The discussion of the posts and actions on the page you linked, are a helpful learning tool for me. One of the threads addresses the possibility of a language affecting  a poster's ability to ask a well-formed question. It was something to chew on for a while.